# java return json object with two json arrays

Tags: java, json, playframework

Hi in my playframework application I want to return an json object with multiple json nodes inside.

I tried this:

```
    JsonNode kundeNode = Json.toJson(kunde);
    JsonNode rechkopfNode = Json.toJson(rechkopf);

    Json.newObject();

    return ok(Json.newObject(
            "kunde" -> kundeNode,
            "rechKopf" -> rechkopfNode
  ));
```

But I got compiler errors. I think thats the scala synthax and not the java.

What would be the correct spelling?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new `ObjectNode` and use the method `.put()` to populate your JSON object.

In your case :

```
JsonNode kundeNode = Json.toJson(kunde);
JsonNode rechkopfNode = Json.toJson(rechkopf);

ObjectNode json = Json.newObject();

json.put("kunde",kundeNode);
json.put("rechKopf",rechkopfNode);

return ok(json);
```